# PyQt5 KeySequenceEdit не отображает клавиши F10... а вместо этого пишет текст

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, keypressevent, qkeysequenceedit

Я хочу отобразить в `KeySequenceEdit` клавиши **`F10`**, **`F11`** и иже с ними, но вместо этого получаю, если это `F10` то показывает "`Media Play`".

Как мне получать не описание этой клавиши, а саму клавишу?

Вот я нажал **`F10`**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QKeySequenceEdit, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence

class KeySequenceEdit(QKeySequenceEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

        sequenceString = self.keySequence().toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        print(QKeySequence().fromString(sequenceString, QKeySequence.PortableText))
        if sequenceString:
            last_key_stroke = sequenceString#.split(',')[-1].strip()
            self.setKeySequence(QKeySequence(last_key_stroke))

class Detector(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 130)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self._keysequenceEdit = KeySequenceEdit()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self._keysequenceEdit)

        button_clear = QPushButton('Clear', clicked=self._keysequenceEdit.clear)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_clear)

        button_print = QPushButton('Print')
        button_print.clicked.connect(self.get_value)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_print)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def get_value(self):
        sequence = self._keysequenceEdit.keySequence()
        sequenceString = sequence.toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        if sequenceString:
            print('Key stroke: {0}'.format(sequenceString))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("""
    QLineEdit {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
    QPushButton {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
""")

demo = Detector()
demo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: запустил ваш код, F10 и получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На моей клавиатуре

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

я получаю **`F10`** при наборе сочетания клавиш <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

<kbd>Fn</kbd> — клавиша-модификатор, и внешне работает подобно другим клавишам-модификаторам, таким как <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> , <kbd>⇧</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> и <kbd>Alt</kbd> . 
При нажатии обычной клавиши-модификатора микроконтроллер в клавиатуре посылает скан-код самого модификатора, который операционная система распознаёт и комбинирует с кодами нажатых в то же время клавиш.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QKeySequenceEdit, \
    QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence

class KeySequenceEdit(QKeySequenceEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

        sequenceString = self.keySequence().toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        print(QKeySequence().fromString(sequenceString, QKeySequence.PortableText))
        print(f'sequenceString: {sequenceString}\n') #
        if sequenceString:
            last_key_stroke = sequenceString#.split(',')[-1].strip()
            self.setKeySequence(QKeySequence(last_key_stroke))


class Detector(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 130)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self._keysequenceEdit = KeySequenceEdit()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self._keysequenceEdit)

        button_clear = QPushButton('Clear', clicked=self._keysequenceEdit.clear)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_clear)

        button_print = QPushButton('Print')
        button_print.clicked.connect(self.get_value)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_print)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def get_value(self):
        sequence = self._keysequenceEdit.keySequence()
        sequenceString = sequence.toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        if sequenceString:
            print('Key stroke: {0}'.format(sequenceString))


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("""
    QLineEdit {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
    QPushButton {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
""")

demo = Detector()
demo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**Update**

> если я просто нажму `F10` выводит "`Media Play`", можно ли в этом случае, например отфильтровать и просто игнорировать такие нажатия?

Все можно, попробуйте:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QKeySequenceEdit, \
    QPushButton, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence


class KeySequenceEdit(QKeySequenceEdit):
    
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

        sequenceString = self.keySequence().toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        print(QKeySequence().fromString(sequenceString, QKeySequence.PortableText))
        if sequenceString:
            last_key_stroke = sequenceString#.split(',')[-1].strip()

            if last_key_stroke == "Media Play":                         # +++
                last_key_stroke = "F10"                                 # +++
            
            self.setKeySequence(QKeySequence(last_key_stroke))


class Detector(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 130)

        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()

        self._keysequenceEdit = KeySequenceEdit()
        mainLayout.addWidget(self._keysequenceEdit)

        button_clear = QPushButton('Clear', clicked=self._keysequenceEdit.clear)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_clear)

        button_print = QPushButton('Print')
        button_print.clicked.connect(self.get_value)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button_print)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

    def get_value(self):
        sequence = self._keysequenceEdit.keySequence()
        sequenceString = sequence.toString(QKeySequence.NativeText)
        if sequenceString:
            print('Key stroke: {0}'.format(sequenceString))
            
        self._keysequenceEdit.setFocus()                                # +++

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyleSheet("""
    QLineEdit {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
    QPushButton {font-size: 25px; height: 40px;}
""")

demo = Detector()
demo.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Да, действительно сочетания fn+F10 выводят "F10", но если я просто нажму F10 выводит "Media Play", можно ли в этом случае, например отфильтровать и просто игнорировать такие нажатия? Так как в дальнейшем текст который отобразиться будет обрабатываться библиотекой keyboard, а она не принимает такие клавиши как "Media Play", "Volume Up" и т. п.

Comment: @User5784 скажите пожалуйста, информация предоставленная в моем ответе была полезна для вас ? и второе, вы все таки нажав на `F10` хотите получить `F10`, а не `Media Play`  ?

Comment: 1) Из вашего ответа я узнал о клавишах-модификаторах, так что можно считать да, но это не решает мою проблему 2) Да

Comment: @User5784 я добавил обновление в свой ответ, проверьте.